# HTML Email template Table help needed

Tags: html-table, html-email, newsletter, email-templates

I need help setting up an email newsletter template as one of the columns is not being displayed properly, the column containing heading 2 is not being displayed properly it is being displayed towards right side of the page instead of aligning with the template elements.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--Table Start-->&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="cont-bg" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" style="background-color: #f1f1f1; padding: 27px 0px 0px; width: 100%; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="1133">&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Main Part Start-->&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 650px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Header Part Start-->&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 650px; height: 682px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="top" mc:edit="view" style="font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; padding-bottom: 22px;">You can&rsquo;t see this email?<a href="#"> View it in your browser.</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><!--Logo Start-->
                                            <td width="287" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background: #fff;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                <p align="left"><br />
                                                    <img src="commstellogo.png" width="208" height="45" border="0" align="left" /></p></td>
                                            <!--Logo End--><!--Menu Part Start-->
                                            <td width="363" height="94" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background: #fff;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 340px;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="right" valign="top" mc:edit="date" style="font: bold 18px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #2f2f2f; text-transform: uppercase; padding-bottom: 8px;">01727 260 101</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 340px;">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td width="16" align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="h-icin" src="images/home-icon.png" width="16" height="19" alt="" /></td>
                                                                            <td width="64" align="left" valign="middle" mc:edit="h-text" style="font: bold 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #414141; padding-left: 9px;"><a href="#" style="color: #414141;">Home</a></td>
                                                                            <td width="16" align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="s-icon" src="images/setting.png" width="16" height="19" alt="" /></td>
                                                                            <td width="79" align="left" valign="middle" mc:edit="s-text" style="font: bold 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #414141; padding-left: 9px;"><a href="#" style="color: #414141;">Services</a></td>
                                                                            <td width="16" align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="a-icon" src="images/about-us.png" width="16" height="19" alt="" /></td>
                                                                            <td width="77" align="left" valign="middle" mc:edit="a-text" style="font: bold 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #414141; padding-left: 9px;"><a href="#" style="color: #414141;">About us</a></td>
                                                                            <td width="18" align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="s-icon" src="images/support.png" width="16" height="19" alt="" /></td>
                                                                            <td width="54" align="right" valign="middle" mc:edit="s-text" style="font: bold 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #414141; padding-left: 9px;"><a href="#">Contact</a></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table></td>
                                            <!--Menu Part End--></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" height="548">&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Banner Start-->&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 650px;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="banner-image" src="#" width="649" height="356" alt="" style="display: block;" /></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#2f2f2f" style="padding: 25px 0px 18px 20px; background: #2f2f2f;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 611px;">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" mc:edit="banner-title" style="font: normal 24px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff; padding-bottom: 8px;">Heading Area</td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" mc:edit="banner-text" style="font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff; line-height: 18px; padding: 0px 0px 12px 4px;">Vivamus interdum mauris urna. Nullam egestas augue elit. Aliquam pretium elit varius metus hendrerit volutpat. <b>20% off</b> Vivamus interdum mauris urna. Nullam egestas augue elit. Aliquam pretium elit varius metus hendrerit volutpat.</td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="#"><img mc:edit="banner-read-more" src="#" width="128" height="31" alt="" /></a></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                &nbsp; <!--Banner End--> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <!--Header Part End--> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><!--Body Part Start--></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="330" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Two column 1 Start-->&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 320px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="two-coulmn-image1" src="businesstelephone.png" width="320" height="172" alt="" style="display: block;" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#2f2f2f" style="padding: 15px 0px 18px 20px; background: #2f2f2f;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 288px;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" mc:edit="banner-title" style="font: normal 24px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff; padding-bottom: 5px;">Heading 2</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" mc:edit="banner-text" style="font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff; line-height: 18px; padding: 0px 0px 12px 4px;">Praesent viverra dui in orci pulvinar convallis. Nunc interdum, metus eget adipiscing rutrum, leo quam accumsan tellus, eget . It's easy and hassle free!</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="#"><img mc:edit="read-more" src="#" width="128" height="31" alt="" /></a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Two column 1 End--> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="320" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Two column 2 Start-->&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 320px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><img mc:edit="two-coulmn-image2" src="mobiles.png" width="320" height="172" alt="" style="display: block;" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#2f2f2f" style="padding: 15px 0px 18px 20px; background: #2f2f2f;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 288px;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" mc:edit="banner-title" style="font: normal 24px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff; padding-bottom: 5px;">Heading 3</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" mc:edit="banner-text" style="font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff; line-height: 18px; padding: 0px 0px 12px 4px;">Nunc vel massa metus, vel varius mi. Sed sagittis consectetur nisi, sed imperdiet ipsum interdum non. Nunc consectetur odio et turpis eleifend semper. Pellentesque lorem purus</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="#"><img mc:edit="read-more-1" src="images/read-more.png" width="128" height="31" alt="" /></a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Two column 2 End--> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--Two column Part End-->
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
            <!--Body Part End--></tr>
        <tr><!--Footer Part Start-->
            <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 687px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background: #fff; padding: 28px 0px 27px 0px;" width="687">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 675px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" mc:edit="un-sp-text" style="font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #737373; line-height: 18px;" width="675">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                <p align="center"><b>Copyright &copy; 2012 Company - Registered &amp; Dales 07765116</b></p></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" mc:edit="c-right-text" style="font: bold 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #737373; line-height: 18px;" width="675">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                <p align="center">Company Address<br />
                                                    T: 023227 000 201 &nbsp;E: <a href="#">admin@admin.com</a> &nbsp;W: <a href="#">company</a></p></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 20px 0px 35px 0px;" width="687">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <p align="center">If you wish to unsubscribe from this email, please click here</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
            <!--Footer Part End--></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--Main Part End--> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <!--Table Start-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you know which column is not displayed correctly, why publish the whole page ?

Comment: im sorry but i thought this might be the best way to explain helpers to solve my issue.

Comment: Try reducing the published code to something minimal where the problem still happens. It will be more readable.

Comment: Thankyou, I will consider your advice, But I need some help here :(

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. I'm not sure anyone will read your code unless you seriously increase its readability.

Comment: And while you're at it, feel free to provide a mockup of what you want to achieve...

Comment: I have to agree with the above.  To debug try with smaller pieces and build up.  

To mockup you could draw in excel the layout you want and post on here as an image?

Answer (score 1):

You're opening a lot of `<table>` tags in your code, but none of them are closed. This means each table will get nested in it's `parent-table` if you will.

Especially with all those the alignment will be out of control.

I suggest closing up the table tags accordingly and removing those `&nbsp;` they make for some mean code.